# Some chunks during RSA encryption on a split file result in too short ciphertext chunks

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to encrypt a large file with public key itself(It is the teacher's requirement, can't use AES keys), even though I know I can only encrypt 128 bytes once at a time with a 1024 bit key. I am splitting the file(any type, .txt.pdf.xls.exe) into 128 byte chunks and encrypt each chunk with my public key.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import base64

def splitter(content,n):
    return [content[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(content), n)]
####################
def encryption(public_key, content):
    list = splitter(content,128)
    enc_data = ''
    for i in list:

        enc_data = enc_data+base64.encodestring(public_key.encrypt(i, None)[0])
        #print len(base64.encodestring(public_key.encrypt(i, None)[0]))
        print base64.encodestring(public_key.encrypt(i, None)[0])
    return enc_data
####################
def decryption(private_key, content):
    list = splitter(content,175)
    dec_data = ''
    for i in list:
        dec_data = dec_data+private_key.decrypt(base64.decodestring(i))
    return dec_data
####################

public_key=RSA.importKey(open('public_key.pem','r').read())
private_key=RSA.importKey(open('private_key.pem','r').read())

f = open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\excel_example.xls','rb').read()

enc = encryption(public_key, f)
print enc

dec = decryption(private_key, enc)
print dec
```

usually, every 128 byte chunk will be converted into a 175 bits base64 code, except some 128 byte chunks became "AA=="

```
KgVqcHadyuHff0EjRC2sq83VbM8joyAp99TKYHjJQJL+l4WZd4rDnC1y/Xd7Vif60gK7Mz3h+8it
iDs4ZDD2chQz4IU0CznoeYUa5o7nl/uwiFppbXx1AlGhRO+L3Olz32eIph2oJlHvmshfMmysnXpJ
zDAqAkOOYBcagonY/7s=
QpHGS7x5bTde8YqifMIOonvUjigjpktYONSDWJU0vSIuODCiG1GPJsum4pOyJ2BseCKzTD8qGMoU
rfbHFBAObjOlkU3RjxCLuOrCk2lSPXC3eNn5DIQqXFtHFX0jfkj/hnrl0R5nQ7R5tmSFTJf2SB5A
c90pAL9hcBP8eEvnAYM=
AA==
AA==
AA==
AA==
AA==
AA==
```

so far, this code is only working with .txt file, it can encrypt .txt in any size, but all other file, I have this "AA==" issue. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using plain or textbook RSA. RSA works only on inputs that are smaller than modulus *N* which is 1024-bit in your case. So there are bound to be inputs that are 128 byte, but numerically bigger than *N* which fails to encrypt.

Use for example 127 byte chunks or 64 byte chunks with RSA padding such as PKCS#1 v1.5 or PKCS#1 v2 OAEP.

As a side note: Your scheme is basically RSA in ECB mode which is not semantically secure. It is also easy to see that reordering the blocks will still produce a plaintext when decrypted, but it will be wrong plaintext. You will have to add something like an HMAC over the complete resulting ciphertext to detect reorderings.

Comment: Besides ECB not being semantically secure, please see [this question/answer about the security pitfalls of plain/raw/textbook RSA](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/1172). Note that this list is not complete as yet.